# How to make a chrome extension which uses python machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, javascript

Actually, I made a video category classifier machine learning model (Deep Learning). Now, I want to make a chrome extension using that model. So, how I have to do that.
I know it's a very broad question but I thankful if you provide some knowledge or some links about that.
I am confused because Chrome extension code would be in JavaScript language. But my model is in python. So, I integrate them. How to run python code using Javascript ?
Any help would be appreciable..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [tensorflow](https://pytorch.org/)/[keras](https://keras.io/) as deep learning framework, maybe the most feasible approach is to use the model with tensorflow.js.

[Tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js) is a javascript implementation of a subset of tensorflow. It can use tensorflow models if you [export them to their json format](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras).

If you are using [pytorch](https://www.tensorflow.org/) as deep learning framework, an option could be exporting your model to [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) and then using [ONNX.js](https://github.com/elliotwaite/pytorch-to-javascript-with-onnx-js).

Note that there are ways to "run" Python code in the browser, like [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/)/[pyscript](https://pyscript.net/), but you will not be able to run libraries that have native components, like deep learning libraries normally have.